# create properties with loop

Tags: python

I would like to create object properties using a loop, and the `setattr` function.
The problem i run into  is that all the properties created with such a loop are equal to one another.

In the following example i create a class `A` with a single attribute `z`, a complex number. i then would like to loop over functions such as numpy's `real` and `imag` to create other properties, such as `z_real` and `z_imag`. The problem then, in the context of this example, is that `z_real == z_imag` is `True`.

```
import numpy as np

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, z):
        self.z = z

        for func in [np.real, np.imag]:
            fget = lambda x: func(x.z)
            print('self.z_%s = %i' % (func.__name__, fget(self)))
            setattr(self.__class__, 'z_%s' % (func.__name__),
                    property(fget))


a = A(1+2j)

print ('a.z_real=%i'% a.z_real)
print ('a.z_imag=%i'% a.z_imag)
```

running this yields

```
self.z_real = 1
self.z_imag = 2
a.z_real=2    
a.z_imag=2
```

It is not clear to me why this is.

Comment: because i want to create many properties in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You're doing it wrong.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271/)

> Don't create more then one instance of the same closure per normal function!

```
fget = lambda x, f=func: f(x.z)
```

Comment: thanks! i browsed that link, and not clear on the issue, there is actually a reasonable debate in the comments. could be characterized as a sloppy use of variable scope? because func was used in the lambda function, but not passed.

Comment: It is *exactly* an issue with scope.

Comment: Here is are two good links on this closure issue: http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/WhatClosuresClose and http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/CPythonCellsClosures.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fget` is a *closure*. It closed over the variable `func`. After the loop is finished, `func` remains set to `np.imag`.

You should do the following afer `self.z = z`:

```
def make_getter(func):
    return lambda x: func(x.z)

for func in [np.real, np.imag]:
    fget = make_getter(func)
```

etc.

Comment: yes, that has been my work around, but i didnt know why my original way dint work untill now.